# Can I use SQL to encrypt a field in Talend?

Tags: sql, encryption, talend

I was asked to encrypt the data of one column in Talend before loading to Oracle. I was given a chunk of SQL for the encryption. Is it possible to use this, or do I have to recreate the method in Java?

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Show us your research. What have you tried ?

Comment: At least show the SQL... But most likely you have to rewrite it in java.

Comment: I'd be happy to show you, but I'd get fired and probably arrested for breaking several laws.

Comment: If the question has been solved and you cannot show any insights you could also delete it now.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a tOracleSP component to call an Oracle function and get the encrypted result by it will probably more expensive than doing it in Java